# Python: how to get the related lines from file?

Tags: python, file, search, printing, strip

How can I get the related lines from a file?
This is my code:

```
read_file = "a.txt"  
read_batch = "b.txt"      

lines_batch = list()
with open(read_file) as r:
    bigstat = r.read()

with open(read_batch) as b:
    for batch in (line_batch.strip() for line_batch in b):
        if batch in bigstat:
            print(???)
```

Bigstat is a txt with 50 lines, but I only want the 2 of them, which contains the batch.

How should I do with this ?
Thank you so much for the help!!!!!!

Comment: Forgot for a second that the data is coming from a file. If you just had a list of strings, would you know how to do this?

Comment: And specify what "related" means here.

Comment: use a for-loop? for line in ...? "related" means the lines which contains the words in batch

Comment: So you need to find the lines in `a.txt` that are exactly the same as a line in `b.txt`?

Comment: I think your first problem is that you're making a lot of confusion with variable names. `lines_batch` is useless because you never put anything in it, and `bigstat` contains the entire file as a string, not as a list, so your condition is very inefficient.

Comment: yes, bu not exactly the same, just the lines which "contains" the words in b.txt

Comment: @Mikk yes....thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that uses only a single for loop and a single if statement to check if a line in the read_file is present in the batch_file (I assume that is what you want to check!).

Just open the files and use `readlines()` to get all the lines individually. Then just iterate through all the lines in the read_file and check if they are in the list of lines in the batch_file (Note that readlines() generates a list whose individual entries are the contents of each line including the ending `\n` character).

```
read_file = "a.txt" 
batch_file = "b.txt" 

with open(read_file) as a: 
    a_lines = a.readlines() 

with open(batch_file) as b: 
    b_lines = b.readlines() 

for line in a_lines: 
    if line in b_lines: 
        print(line.strip())
```

**Edit:**

To get the number of the line in the read_file that contains the match to a line in the batch_file, you have to change the way you go through the read_file. In this case, use `enumerate` to get not only the content of each line but also the number of each line (in this case stored in the variable `i`).

I then just printed the number and content of the matched lines in the read_file and the batch_file.

`i` gets you the number of the line in the read_file.
`a_lines[i]` gets you the corresponding list item (= content of the line)
`b_lines.index(line)` gets you the number of the item `line` in the `b_lines` list (= number of the line in the batch_file)
`line.strip()` gets you the content of that line in the batch_file without the trailing `\n` character.

See the attached expanded code:

```
read_file = "a.txt" 
batch_file = "b.txt" 

with open(read_file) as a: 
    a_lines = a.readlines() 

with open(batch_file) as b: 
    b_lines = b.readlines() 

for i, line in enumerate(a_lines):
    if line in b_lines:
        print("Number of line in read_file is %i" % i)
        print("Content of line in read_file is %s" % a_lines[i].strip())

        print("Number of line in batch_file is %i" % b_lines.index(line))
        print("Content of line in batch_file is %s" % line.strip())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helps me a lot! May I ask you another question: How can I get the a_lines which contains the line. I tried with str.find and str.index and both of them just give me the position back...

Comment: Hey, you are welcome! I have added some code in my original answer that should show you how to get not only the content of each line, but also the number of each line. And I would greatly appreciate if your problem is solved that you mark my answer as accepted! Just click on the green check mark on the left.